# 'as' operator precedence in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Do I need to write:

```
const response = (await got(url)) as got.Response<MyResponseType>;
```

or is this enough?

```
const response = await got(url) as got.Response<MyResponseType>;
```

I could not find a definitive resource on type casting operator precedence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second example works. Typecasting is always the last step, if not specified otherwise by using parenthesis.

Comment: It does, thanks. I should also note that since we're using Prettier, the braces will be added back automatically even if I remove them .